# .ICS calendar authentication from third-party https:// URL

Tags: ios, ssl, calendar

I have code that generates .ICS scheduling information customized for people and each is saved to the server.  A link is displayed on the frontend which just displays the custom link (along with information on how to sync using Outlook, Google Calendar or Apple iCal).

Everything is working okay so far, Google Calendar seems to refresh consistently, Outlook is a bit of a pain but there are workarounds.  When I went to test on an iPad and tried to 'Add a Subscribed Calendar', it keeps saying that it couldn't connect using SSL

I'm not too entrenched in the Apple ecosystem at this point, is it an SSL thing with Apple products where you have to authenticate or need a valid SSL certificate to access the .ICS file?

Thanks for any considerations

Comment: SSL certificate is required for connection to server but for accessing .ICS file, there is no need of it.

Comment: Appreciate the prompt response Prince.  I apologize for not submitting a link, the ICS file contains sensitive information that I can't really share at this point.  Just know that it's formed correctly (works in Outlook and Google so far) and that when i paste the URL of the .ICS file into a browser,  the events come up and I'm prompted to 'Add' them all.  I don't want to do that, because I think that it's just a snapshot of the events at one point in time, and it isn't being synced because of the way the events are added in this case (via URL in browser and not added as a Subscribed Calendar